# Запятая перед "и" в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

В начале творческого развития вырубные фигурки -  самый удобный вид раскрашивания для малышей, карандаш не выходит за границы рисунка, и готовая работа выглядит как красивая поделка

Comment: Вопрос сформулируйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

- Есть вырубные инструменты, а фигурки - вырубленные
- Не вид раскрашивания, а вид раскрасок.
- "начало творческого развития для малышей" вполне можно упростить до "творческого развития малышей"
- "удобный для творческого развития" лучше заменить на "полезный для творческого развития"

**Вырубленные из картона фигурки - самый полезный для творческого развития малышей вид раскрасок: карандаш не выходит за границы рисунка, и конечный результат выглядит как красивая поделка.**

UPD. Поделюсь своими мыслями по поводу знаков препинания. Перед нами сложное предложение, состоящее из трех простых. Обозначим их буквами A, Б, В.
Очевидно, что после А должно стоять двоеточие, заменяющее союз "потому что". Далее, может показаться что два простых придаточных Б и В вводятся общим двоеточием (незримо присутствующим союзом "потому что") - и тогда запятая между Б и В не нужна. Однако между Б и В есть причинно-следственная связь -  и значит запятая все-таки нужна.

UPD2. Еще раз подумав, решил, что у нас по смыслу все-таки самый удобный, а не самый полезный вид раскрасок. А вместо неудачного «удобный для творческого развития» можно написать «удобный (для использования) в процессе творческого развития»

**Вырубленные из картона фигурки - самый удобный в процессе творческого развития малышей вид раскрасок: карандаш не выходит за границы рисунка, и конечный результат выглядит как красивая поделка.**

Answer (score 1):

Вырубные  фигурки ― самый подходящий вид раскрашивания для творческого развития малышей: карандаш не выходит за границы рисунка и конечный результат выглядит как красивая поделка.

**Примечания**

**1) запятую  не надо ставить**, союз И связывает два предложения в одну фразу, которая поясняет первое предложение.

[**Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Например:
*Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой* (Пауст.).

2) **вырубные фигурки ―  термин,** например: КОМПЛЕКТ ВЫРУБНЫХ ФИГУРОК "АССОРТИ" 18 ШТ. ЦВЕТ СВЕТЛО-ЗЕЛЕНЫЙ МАТОВЫЙ

[**Вырубные фигурки из картона**](https://market.yandex.ru/search?clid=545&cvredirect=0&text=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0&deliveryincluded=0&onstock=1)

Answer (score 0):

Фигурки есть вид раскрашивания.Действительно надо ставить тире. Далее идет пояснение, почему же это именно так. Надо использовать запятую и союзы "так как" или "потому что", а при их отсутствии - двоеточие. Ну и запятая перед и необходима, так как разделяет две равнозначные части предложения с разными грамматическими основами. 
Теперь о вырубных фигурках. Это действительно формы для вырубания (тогда это ВЫРУБНЫЕ ФОРМЫ), или ВЫРУБЛЕННЫЕ из чего-либо (дерева, картона) фигурки? Теперь имеем следующее. В начале творческого развития вырубные формы - самый удобный вид раскрашивания для малышей: карандаш не выходит за границы рисунка, и готовая работа выглядит как красивая поделка. ИЛИ В начале творческого развития вырубленные из картона фигурки - самый удобный вид раскрашивания для малышей: карандаш не выходит за границы рисунка, и готовая работа выглядит как красивая поделка. Или уж если совсем правильно... Для малышей в начале творческого развития самый удобный вид раскрашивания - вырубленные из картона фигурки: карандаш не выходит за границы рисунка, и конечный результат выглядит как красивая поделка.